# Bootstrap 4: Dynamical add row month name to table

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a table with the date in the first column and the description in the second column.

Now I would like to be automatically added month names above the first line of the date as shown in the picture. I ask for any suggestion in what way could I do this? I didn't find anything like it anywhere on the web.

[image: screenshot of table]

Comment: I guess we need more details:

1) Don´t you know how to get the name of the current month?
use e.g. $month_name=date('F', strtotime($your_current_date)); // F gives monthname, see https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

or 2) Do you have a problem in processing your while / foreach?

or 3) Do you have a problem in writing your html-code?

Comment: I can get date and i have already table creates i want do the upgrade that javascript aoutomaticaly add row with month name. i think this will be easiest to do with javascript.  i have a problem with the process or code.  an example code would be welcome

Comment: than please update your question and add some more information, so other people can help easier.
But this is a complex javascript feature. Maybe easier to do by php serverside?!

Comment: i find the solution on this site with them code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176141/display-posts-by-month

thank you wery much

Comment: i dont know how to close this question if anone know do this